# POpen works with string but not variable

Tags: c, curl, segmentation-fault, popen

I can get the following to work fine :

```
fp = popen("curl http://192.168.0.144:8000/adder?wsdl", "r");
```

But when I try it like so:

```
char* cmd;
strcpy(cmd, "curl http://");
strcat(cmd, qrdata->ip_addr);
strcat(cmd, ":8000/adder?wsdl");

fp = popen(cmd, "r");
```

a segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: How is `ip_addr` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to allocate memory to `char * cmd`.

If using gcc you can use `asprintf()` to allocate as much buffer as necessary to have the formatted string printed into:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

...

char * cmd = NULL;
asprintf(&cmd, "curl http://%s:8000/adder?wsdl", qrdata->ip_addr);

/* Use cmd. */

free(cmd);
```

Note: The example above assumes `qrdata->ip_addr` is a `0`-terminated character array.

Answer (score 5):

you need to allocate memory for cmd:

```
    char cmd [256];
```

whereby `256-1 = 255` is the maximum number of characters that your string can have

Comment: That's a very conservative buffer. As in "too small for the example shown in the question"-conservative. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized the `cmd` variable.

Do

```
char* cmd = new char[MAX_LEN];
```

and of course you need to define `MAX_LEN`

```
#define MAX_LEN 1024
```